# Как правильно записать вложенную функцию?

Tags: python, массивы, функции, numpy

[image: Cама функция S]Имеется функция подобия, берущая значения из другой функции и считающая значение S.
Необходимо из первой функции передать x2[200:],x2,x1 и посчитать, построить график. Как это сделать лучше всего? Я пытался сделать с помощью вложенной функции, но так как необходимой информации для того как записать цикл не нашел-результата не получил.

Код имеет следующий вид:

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import *
from scipy import *
from pylab import figure, show, setp
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



#We define a function which is going to be the recursive function.
def num_rossler(x1_n, y1_n, z1_n, x2_n, y2_n, z2_n, h, a, b, c, k, w1, w2):
    x1_n1=x1_n+h*(-w1*y1_n-z1_n+K*(x2_n-x1_n)) # dx/dt = x1 + h*( - y1 - z1 + k (x2 - x1 ))
    y1_n1=y1_n+h*(w1*x1_n+a*y1_n)
    z1_n1=z1_n+h*(b+z1_n*(x1_n-c))   
 
    x2_n1=x2_n+h*(-w2*y2_n-z2_n+K*(x1_n-x2_n))
    y2_n1=y2_n+h*(w2*x2_n+a*y2_n)
    z2_n1=z2_n+h*(b+z2_n*(x2_n-c))
    def simi_func(s,x1_n, y1_n, z1_n, x2_n, y2_n, z2_n):
        s=((x2_n1[200:]-x1_n1[:999800])**2/(x1_n1[:999800]**2*x2_n1[:999800]**2)**(1/2))**(1/2)
        return s_n
    return x1_n1, y1_n1, z1_n1, x2_n1, y2_n1, z2_n1
    



#Now we prepare some variables
#First the parameters
a=0.165
b=0.2
c=10
K=0.1
w1=0.99
w2=0.95
 
#Them the time interval and the step size
t_ini=0
t_fin=10000
h=0.01
numsteps=int((t_fin-t_ini)/h)
 
#using this parameters we build the time.
t=numpy.linspace(t_ini,t_fin,numsteps)
#And the vectors for the solutions
x1=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
y1=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
z1=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
 
x2=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
y2=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
z2=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
s=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
 
 
#We set the initial conditions
x1[0]=0.001
y1[0]=0.001
z1[0]=0.001
 
x2[0]=0.002
y2[0]=0.002
z2[0]=0.002

n=x1.size-1
 
#This is the main loop where we use the recursive system to obtain the solution

for k in range(0, n):
    #We use the previous point to generate the new point using the recursion
    [x1[k+1],y1[k+1],z1[k+1],x2[k+1],y2[k+1],z2[k+1]]=num_rossler(x1[k],y1[k],z1[k],x2[k],y2[k],z2[k],t[k+1]-t[k],a,b,c,K,w1,w2)
    [s[k+1]]=simi_func(s[k])
#Now that we have the solution in vectors t,x,y,z is time to plot them.
print(s)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1[:2000] ,s[:2000]*0.01)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
show()
```

В принципе, он прекрасно работает и считает значения х1,х2 и тд. Но как посчитать S(simi_func)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот так что-то считает и рисует. Наверняка ещё можно упростить, если правильно понять задачу. Я так и не понял, зачем вам нужно было вызывать `simi_func` в цикле, ведь там каждый раз на выходе все значения `s` считаются, весь миллион, или сколько их там. Что с ними делать - перезаписывать? Так проще по всем `x`, `y` тогда в конце это `s` разом посчитать. Либо я ничего не понял.

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import *
from scipy import *
from pylab import figure, show, setp
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



#We define a function which is going to be the recursive function.
def num_rossler(x1_n, y1_n, z1_n, x2_n, y2_n, z2_n, h, a, b, c, k, w1, w2):
    x1_n1=x1_n+h*(-w1*y1_n-z1_n+K*(x2_n-x1_n)) # dx/dt = x1 + h*( - y1 - z1 + k (x2 - x1 ))
    y1_n1=y1_n+h*(w1*x1_n+a*y1_n)
    z1_n1=z1_n+h*(b+z1_n*(x1_n-c))   
 
    x2_n1=x2_n+h*(-w2*y2_n-z2_n+K*(x1_n-x2_n))
    y2_n1=y2_n+h*(w2*x2_n+a*y2_n)
    z2_n1=z2_n+h*(b+z2_n*(x2_n-c))
    return x1_n1, y1_n1, z1_n1, x2_n1, y2_n1, z2_n1
    
def simi_func(x1,x2):
    s=((x2[200:]-x1[:999800])**2/(x1[:999800]**2*x2[:999800]**2)**(1/2))**(1/2)
    return s


#Now we prepare some variables
#First the parameters
a=0.165
b=0.2
c=10
K=0.1
w1=0.99
w2=0.95
 
#Them the time interval and the step size
t_ini=0
t_fin=10000
h=0.01
numsteps=int((t_fin-t_ini)/h)
 
#using this parameters we build the time.
t=numpy.linspace(t_ini,t_fin,numsteps)
#And the vectors for the solutions
x1=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
y1=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
z1=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
 
x2=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
y2=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
z2=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
s=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
 
 
#We set the initial conditions
x1[0]=0.001
y1[0]=0.001
z1[0]=0.001
 
x2[0]=0.002
y2[0]=0.002
z2[0]=0.002

n=x1.size-1
 
#This is the main loop where we use the recursive system to obtain the solution

for k in range(0, n):
    #We use the previous point to generate the new point using the recursion
    x1[k+1],y1[k+1],z1[k+1],x2[k+1],y2[k+1],z2[k+1]=num_rossler(x1[k],y1[k],z1[k],x2[k],y2[k],z2[k],t[k+1]-t[k],a,b,c,K,w1,w2)

#Now that we have the solution in vectors t,x,y,z is time to plot them.
s=simi_func(x1,x2)
print(s)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1[:2000] ,s[:2000]*0.01)
#plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim(-0.08,0.11)
plt.show()
```

Вывод:

```
[16.37640855 16.64348818 17.15763265 ...  3.01383473  3.06287398
  3.11391084]
```

График:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще, миллион значений необходим чтобы сделать усреднение(угловые скобки), но пока это не до конца реализовано. Спасибо за ответ.